# Ruby not finding gems, but they appear on gem list, and work in irb console?

Tags: ruby

I've got a Ruby app using deamon-kit to create a daemon that runs a cron task every 3 seconds.

Problem is I'm trying to add some error checking using Errbit, so that requires me to:

```
require 'hoptoad_notifier'
```

in my script. However, the script is complaining it can't find the file?

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@stitch/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- hoptoad_notifier (LoadError)
```

What confuses me is that the gem is installed, when I run

```
gem list | grep hoptoad_notifier
```

I get

```
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11)
```

Another test I did was to pop into irb console, on the same terminal window, after making sure I'm inside the correct RVM gemset off course:

```
1.9.2p320 :001 > require 'hoptoad_notifier'
 => true
1.9.2p320 :002 >
```

And voila, hoptoad is loading. It's only when loading my deamon-kit deamon, that I get the error.

What further confuses me is that when I look at my require block:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'resque'
require 'hoptoad_notifier'
```

It's finding rubygems and resque, but not hoptoad_notifier? Why, when I comment out hoptoad, it doesn't also complain about resque and rubygems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dameon-kit uses bundler, so you don't need to include rubygems. Include the following lines to your Gemfile :

```
gem 'resque'
gem 'hoptoad_notifier'
```

Run `bundle install`

and include your gems as usual :

```
require 'resque'
require 'hoptoad_notifier'
```

It worked for me.

Comment: The version is most definitely the same. I'm using RVM, so beware. Did you run it as a deamon-kit project?